# Why isn't `"checkJS": true` working with Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, typescript

I'm experimenting with using TypeScript to the extent possible in Lightning Web Components (as described in [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/04/how-to-use-typescript-with-salesforce-part-2)), and while it works if I put `// @ts-check` at the top of my JavaScript file, removing this line and including `"checkJs": true` in `tsconfig.json` removes the error reporting that TypeScript gives when the check line is the first line of the file.

How can I avoid having to put `// @ts-check` at the top of all my JS files? Do I need to specify a path for TypeScript to find the JavaScript files? All our components are found in `force-app/core/lwc/`, although if we decide to use TypeScript across our projects, we would have additional `lwc` folders (all within `force-app`).

I did find this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21435), where a reply says:

> And thus `--checkJs` really means nothing without `--allowJs`.

So I tried enabling that as well with no change in results. Errors are still not reported without `// @ts-check` in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/04/how-to-use-typescript-with-salesforce-part-2) same article , we need to specify `target` compiler in `jsconfig.json` file of `lwc` folder.

Below is the added config :

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "target": "ESNext"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*",
        "../../../../.sfdx/typings/lwc/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
```

The blog also states to add `//@ts-nocheck` for skipping type checking :

> With the checkJs flag added, you don’t need to add //@ts-check to each
> file anymore. Instead, to skip type checking on specific files, add
> the //@ts-nocheck flag at the beginning of those files.

Above changes worked for me. Let me know if it helps.

**Edit** : `tsconfig.json` is required for LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) apps. For LWC , we need to define configs in `jsconfig.json`

Comment: My `jsconfig.json` already had the paths included, but the `compilerOptions` didn't include the `checkJs` property. Adding that here, instead of to `tsconfig.json`, seems to have fixed the problem.